# How can pandas to_excel with columns merged only?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

As below codes showed, I want to use `pandas` to collect some and generate a excel with `to_excel`.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel


columns = [['2020-04', 'AMZ', 'EC', 'DL'], ['2020-04', 'AMZ', 'EC', 'DRL'], ['2020-04', 'AMZ', 'Fin', 'BFI'],
['2020-04', 'Google', 'GAME', 'BV'], ['2020-04', 'Google', 'GAME', 'DRL'], ['2020-04', 'Google', 'GAME', 'DRL-CN'], ['index_total', '', '', '']]

data = {0: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4684.41], 1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 2:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6680.65], 3: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14453.25], 4: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48609.45], 5: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7250.23], 6: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 7: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
, 0.0, 1735632.01], 8: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 98941.92], 9: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1939.64]}

indices = {0: ['backend', 'entity 1', 'type_1'],
           1: ['backend', 'entity 1', 'type_1'],
           2: ['backend', 'entity 12', 'type_2'],
           3: ['backend', 'entity 12', 'type_2'],
           4: ['backend', 'entity 14', 'type_2'],
           5: ['backend', 'entity 15', 'type_2'],
           6: ['backend', 'entity 12', 'type_2'],
           7: ['frontend', 'entity 1', 'type_23'],
           8: ['frontend', 'entity 1', 'type_4'],
           9: ['frontend', 'entity 6', 'type_7'],

           }

header_indices = ["data_source", "entity", "settle_type"]

indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indices.values(), names=header_indices)
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values(), index=indices, columns=columns)

print(df)
# to_excel
df.to_excel("demo.xlsx", merge_cells=True)
```

Then I got a dataframe like

```
                                   2020-04            ...               index_total
                                      AMZ            ... Google                   
                                       EC       Fin  ...   GAME                   
                                       DL  DRL  BFI  ...    DRL DRL-CN            
data_source entity    settle_type                    ...                          
backend     entity 1  type_1          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0     4684.41
                      type_1          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0        0.00
            entity 12 type_2          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0     6680.65
                      type_2          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    14453.25
            entity 14 type_2          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    48609.45
            entity 15 type_2          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0     7250.23
            entity 12 type_2          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0        0.00
frontend    entity 1  type_23         0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0  1735632.01
                      type_4          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    98941.92
            entity 6  type_7          0.0  0.0  0.0  ...    0.0    0.0     1939.64
```

And if I export it to excel directly using `to_excel` I would get

[image]

But my expected output is :

[image]

How to adjust dataframe format to export expected excel file?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please point to the differences between what you get and what you're expecting to get? I couldn't identify them. (sorry)

Comment: @Roy2012 thanks for replying, i've updated  more detail info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `xlsxwriter` for this by first writing the dataframe to the excel and then merging the required cells. Since you are resetting the index you will have to drop the new index from the excel manually as `to_excel` does not support `index=False` for a dataframe with multi-index columns.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = writer.book
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'border': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter'})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
writer.sheets['Sheet1'] = worksheet

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

worksheet.merge_range('B1:B4', df.columns[0][0], merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range('C1:C4', df.columns[1][0], merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range('D1:D4', df.columns[2][0], merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range('K1:K4', df.columns[9][0], merge_format)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how can I delete one clolumn by using `xlsxwriter`, I googled it but nothing  related found.

Comment: It is not possible I think. You can give `openpyxl` a try.

Comment: I tried deleting the column with `openpyxl`, but it is messing up the merged cells.